# SSRS 2016 Mobile Report Publisher - No Data Metrics

Tags: sql, reporting-services, sql-server-2016

I am trying to create a new mobile report using the SSMS 2016 SQL Server Report Publisher. Each time I try to create a new graph using the data from my data source, SSMS doesn't recognize any metrics to display on the graph. It appears that each of my columns have a filter-esque symbol next to the text, prohibiting me from using that column as a metric. How can I alter my data to remove this symbol and furthermore, what does this symbol represent?

Visual Example:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer: You cannot analyze data that is not aggregated. For example, the data in your data tables must be either be evaluated through the count function, sum function, avg function, etc. or else it cannot be used in the reporting services.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen, the data types are important to your metric that you want to plot must be a `numeric/integer/money` data type.